# How to get multi-currency info in your org

Tags: apex, soql, rest-api

Is there a way to get multi-currency information using `apex or soql or with any rest endpoints`?

Setup==>Company Information==> Currency Setup (top)

My scenario is to get a list of currency setup for an particular origination.

I have looked in the `Organization` object but did not find any info.
Also I have looked `/services/data/40.0/connect/organization` did not find any info related with multi-currency.

I'm wondering is that even possible to get the information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for:

> ## [`DatedConversionRate`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_datedconversionrate.htm)
>
> Represents the dated exchange rates used by an organization for which the multicurrency and the effective dated currency features are enabled.

Or possibly:

> ## [`CurrencyType`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_currencytype.htm)
>
> Represents the currencies used by an organization for which the multicurrency feature is enabled.

Comment: Was just about to edit that in for you.